# Was 'libclamav_llvm.dll' missing after build ClamAV version 0.98.6

Tags: dll, antivirus

So i've just started to replace ClamAV engine version 0.97.6 with the newer version 0.98.6, and i did noticed that the **'libclamav_llvm.dll'** is missing after the build, looked at the .dll's and .exe files we had for the older version.
So how about that was it removed, renamed, or my build wasn't successful?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find libclamav_llvm.dll in following path. It was not removed in new version.

ClamWinPortable_0.98.6_Apps_Eng/App/clamwin/bin/libclamav_llvm.dll